# Insert Value from One Column to a New Blank Column Based on Score Value

Tags: excel, vba, insert, lookup

I want to insert the name of a company from one column into a new blank one, only if the corresponding value in the "Score" column is equal to or less than 5.

A simple Vlookup cannot be used because this template has to deal with potentially dynamic data, i.e. the column location of the "Score" column may change next quarter etc.

VBA does not alert to any bugs in the code below, but when it is run nothing happens.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub MacroX()
   Dim Score_Col As Long

   For i = 1 To NumCols
      If Cells(1, i).Value = "SCORE" Then Score_Col = i
   Next

   For i = 2 To NumRows
      If Cells(i, Score_Col).Value <= 5 Then Cells(i, 28).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, for one I would use `Range.Find` to locate the right column for "Score". Second, what is `Numrows` and where is it defined (and `Numcols`).

Comment: Also do you need VBA? This could be a formula, no?  Also ...where do you define `NumCols` and `NumRows`?

Comment: What happens if the "Score" column is either 28 or 2? Are you doing anything else with this macro? This could be done with a formula

Comment: Did you try with debug.print Score_Col ? Does it display an integer like 1 2 3 ect... ?

Comment: Both `NumCols` and `NumRows` are undeclared variables, and thus empty. Your loops run from `1 To Empty` and `2 To Empty`, thus not iterating at all. Your code works, but won't do anything. Use `Option Explicit` to avoid such errors (undeclared variables) and actually assign a value to those variables.